# What git workflow for web serial literature

Tags: git

I want to publish a fiction in the form of a web serial, using `git` as a multi-tool. It's a fan fiction of [Worm](https://parahumans.wordpress.com/) by J.C. "Wildbow" McCrae. The original fiction is divided in arcs, themselves divided into chapters and interludes of various lengths, and I intend to keep the same structure. I think `git` would be the best tool for versioning, publishing via `github` or `gitlab`, and submitting corrections before and after publication.

But although I use `git` for simple day-to-day versioning, I don't know the tool well enough to choose the best workflow for such a task. To be honest, I'm not even comfortable with branches. And it's not a classic kind of project. The structure is different from a code project: each chapter is published chronologically but is independent of the others.

So far, I've done a schema to illustrate how I want to produce and publish my content. **EVEN IF IT LOOKS LIKE ONE, IT ISN'T A GIT WORKFLOW**. It was at first, but I thought it reflected poorly a real git workflow. After that, it becomes more an illustration of how each chapter will evolve independently from the others while being published in a chronologic order and maintained or even rewritten after.

So, how can I use `git`to produce, publish and maintain web serial content?
What would be the best `git` workflow for my project?

Sorry if my post is unclear, my English isn't that good but don't hesitate to ask me for any clarification.

Thanks for reading me and every constructive input is welcomed!

[image]

EDIT: clarifications, rewording, relocated some info for better visibility

Comment: Hi, I recommend you [edit] your post and upload the image to Stack Overflow using the image button.  This will make it easier for people to view the image because they won't have to load the whole _imgur.com_ page, just the image itself.
Also, I am a little confused about the meaning of the green/yellow/red commits.  Do they have something to do with rewrites?
I am also having trouble figuring out exactly how the blue numbers are derived.

Comment: Hi @ThomasF thanks for your recommendation. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation here to post images directly in my post. but it seems a good idea to write it in the post.  About the red arrows, they're not really commits as I said before it's not a git workflow. Color is more used here to diferentiate the steps of production and/or publication processes.

Comment: Ah, I thought you could at least add a link to the picture. If you can't, you could at least add a `.jpg` to the link so only the picture is opened when someone clicks on the link.
And to clarify your question, are you asking: "how could I use Git to do this" or "how can I do this without Git" or something else  (or both)?
You could also consider the [workflow] tag for your question.

Comment: Thanks to the edits suggested by @Mukesh A, I can now have an image directly in-post.

Comment: @ThomasF My question is "How can I use `git`to do this. Edit: edited the post in consequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

After reviewing your comment and updated image, I believe perhaps using either a    git subtree, Google repo. These two workflows are a little more complex than the standard Git Workflow, but allow you to keep individual repos within one main project. You can read a quick intro to git subtree [here](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree). Google repo may be a little harder to hit the ground running but documentation is located [here](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/repo).

*Note: I have not used either workflow only just now tested the subtree workflow*

**Quick Rundown of subtree**

```
Main
|
|_chapter1(subtree)
|_chapter2(subtree)


git subtree add --prefix *your directory here* https://*repo address here* master
```

This will add the repo into your project with latest commits and preserve the history of changes. We can use --squash at the end to eliminate history from the main project if desired.

```
git subtree pull --prefix *your directory here* https://*repo address here* master
```

This will update the subtree. The [article](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree) I referenced goes on to explain how this can all be done without the use of subtree commands. Thank you for the info [Nicola Paolucci](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/author/npaolucci)

I believe what you are describing closely resembles trunk based development. You will have a Release branch, a trunk branch, and individual branches for the chapters. I was completely unfamiliar with web serials. I read the paragraph in Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_fiction#Web_serial). As demonstrated in your diagram the individual chapters do not derive from the rest, but I hope that having the files from the project in each branch isn't an issue.

**If it is not a problem** to include the preexisting files from the whole project, this workflow should suffice. Each time you begin work on one of the chapters you would create a branch off of the trunk. You then bring it back to the trunk when it is ready for Production(where you will allow readers to see the finalized content).

You would have **Master** then create a **Chapter 1** branch merge this into **Master** then **Master** out to **Production**. You then would make a new **Chapter 1** branch to edit further or other branches for each chapter.

If you would like to read about this as a possible workflow you could start [here](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/).
This [link](https://uploads.toptal.io/blog/image/124319/toptal-blog-image-1507018418276-5236f6ebfd31c78b442562d4d202763c.png) has a visual for trunk based workflows.

Comment: Well for now trunk-workflow is more or less what I use because I don't have much content to manage, but I suspect it will be an issue to have all files from the project in each branches. I'm not confortable with the idea to have to edit _chapter 1_ after having started to work on _chapter 4_ and I suspect I'll mess it up when it's time to merge.

Comment: So it would have any files from the moment you create that branch. In the software world, they call them feature branches. You won't need to keep the individual branches up to date with the trunk branch. They exist only until brought back to the trunk. 
Is it more than one person working on the project? 
Is your worry it will be confusing which files your working on in each branch?

Comment: Yes, I worry about confusing files or changes and having to manage conflicts. Perhaps branches aren't what I need. Ideally, I'd have separated historics for each chapter. I could edit each chapter independently. When a chapter would be in a satisfying state, I'd overwrite (I don't know how) its previous version in master. So I'd have a master that would only be constituted from the last version of each published chapter. Additionnaly, I need to be able to submit a beta version of each chapter for external people, but I'd be the only one to edit the content.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I think I'll go this way even if it's not perfect. In particular, it lacks the 'simplicity' of just one repo. Sorry for the late answer, it took me a long time to figure your answer and find what I really wanted to do with no perfect solution, finally changing my expectations. Thnaks again for your help.

Comment: I upvoted your answer but don't have sufficient rep to have it shown. :-P

Comment: No problem I hope it works out for you. Thank you for marking it as the chosen answer.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>First off, I have to say, I love the addition of the legend in the picture.</sub>

This answer focuses on how to go about branching and committing and merging.  I don't really focus on how the file-system is set up.  I am more looking at how the log of commits will look in the end.

---

If I were to go about writing a web series of arcs and chapters, I might go about it something like this.

I would use write chapters in descriptive branches so that when I merged the changes into production, Git would automatically make a nice merge commit message that has the basics of what was done on that branch.

```
mkdir arc_01 arc_02  # Create a few directories to start with
git init             # master is the branch automatically created
echo "Worm Serial Table of Contents" >> table_of_contents.txt
git add table_of_contents.txt
git commit -m "Initial commit. Includes table of contents"

git branch published # create publishable branch

# start creating content
git checkout -b arc-01-chapter-01-draft   # Checkout branch for the chapter one
echo "Arc 1, Chapter 1" > arc_01/chapter_01.txt # start writing chapter
git add arc_01/chapter_01.txt
git commit -m "First draft of arc 1, chapter 1"

# continue with first chapter
echo "It was a dark and stormy night and\
 everything was dreary" >> arc_01/chapter_01.txt
git add arc_01/chapter_01.txt
git commit -m "Finished draft of arc 1, chapter 1"

# Merge with production branch
git checkout -b production master # create the production branch at master
git merge --no-ff arc-01-chapter-01-draft

# By checking out production then merging into the branch you were just
#  working on, Git will auto-fill the merge commit with a useful description of:
#      "Merge branch 'arc-01-chapter-01-draft' into production"

# Then you can delete the draft branch because you don't need it right now
git branch -d arc-01-chapter-01-draft
```

Okay, that is one stage done.  Next: logging and beta.

```
# Now we can see our progress by doing some kind of git log
git log --decorate --graph --oneline --all
#  *   726e661 (HEAD -> production) Merge branch 'arc-01-chapter-01-draft' into production
#  |\
#  | * 29c00f7 Finished draft of arc 1, chapter 1
#  | * e8cbcd6 First draft of arc 1, chapter 1
#  |/
#  * d419ebf (published, master) Initial commit. Includes table of contents
```

Then, when you want to start doing the beta draft, you can `checkout` a new branch.

```
git checkout -b arc-01-chapter-01-beta production
# checkout the next branch at the current production point

# Edit the first chapter (in this case, rewrite it all)
echo "Arc 1, Chapter 1" >> arc_01/chapter_01.txt
echo "It was a dark and silent night, and everything was calm." >> arc_01/chapter_01.txt
git add arc_01/chapter_01.txt

# Finish revisions
git commit -m "Beta revisions for arc 1, chapter 1"

# Merge production into the new update
git checkout production
git merge --no-ff arc-01-chapter-01-beta

git branch -d arc-01-chapter-01-beta

# Now you are ready to publish chapter 1
git checkout published
git merge --ff-only production

git log --decorate --graph --oneline --all
# *   c9da9d7 (HEAD -> published, production) Merge branch 'arc-01-chapter-01-beta' into production
# |\
# | * a3f9294 Beta revisions for arc 1, chapter 1
# |/
# *   726e661 Merge branch 'arc-01-chapter-01-draft' into production
# |\
# | * 29c00f7 Finished draft of arc 1, chapter 1
# | * e8cbcd6 First draft of arc 1, chapter 1
# |/
# * d419ebf (master) Initial commit. Includes table of contents
```

In this way you could work on multiple chapter as once.  There would be multiple branches in progress at once.  When you want to work on a different chapter, you can `checkout` the new chapter and continue writing.

This method assumes that you will have no more then one active branch for each chapter.

The is also lots of room to add git `alias`es and scripts to automate repetitive tasks in your workflow.
For example, some simple alias for some of the tasks above might be:

```
git config --local alias.new 'checkout production -b'
git config --local alias.updateProduction '!git checkout production; git merge --no-ff'
git config --local alias.publish '!git checkout published; git merge --ff-only production'
```

And use it like:

```
git new arc-01-chapter-01-typos
# edit chapter 1...
# commit chapter 1...
git updateProduction arc-01-chapter-01-typos
git publish
```

Which results in:

```
* 856834e (HEAD -> published, production) Merge branch 'arc-01-chapter-01-typos' into production
|\
| * ed6e595 Added better ending to chapter 1
|/
*   c9da9d7 Merge branch 'arc-01-chapter-01-beta' into production
|\
| * a3f9294 Beta revisions for arc 1, chapter 1
|/
*   726e661 Merge branch 'arc-01-chapter-01-draft' into production
|\
| * 29c00f7 Finished draft of arc 1, chapter 1
| * e8cbcd6 First draft of arc 1, chapter 1
|/
* d419ebf (master) Initial commit. Includes table of contents
```

I could also show an example of working on two branches at once, but I think this is enough to go on.  (Or I can explain more if need be).

<sub>A Note: the auto-generated merge messages can be used without starting an editor using `git merge --no-edit`.  However, the git manual page discouraged this for some reason.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your *very* thorough answer. Unfortunately I think I'll go for the subtree way. Although your input gave me some insight about `git` and its traditional branch workflow. The main reason I won't be using it is because I want to easily work on any number of chapter at the same time and I think subtree will be a lot more straigtforward to do it. Sorry for the late answer, I had a hard time understanding the implications of the answers I got, and figuring what I wanted and how to do with no completely satisfying answer. Thanks a lot for your input!

Comment: I upvoted your answer but don't have sufficient rep to have it shown. :-P

Comment: I see your point.  If you wanted to be working on two drafts at once, you would have to do something like: `<save chapter 1>;git checkout chapter-2-draft;<open chapter 2>`.  It could get very cumbersome.  And there would be cases where it would be impossible to have a working draft of two different chapters open at the same time.

Comment: Yes, that's the main problem. I though I could compensate the non-linear commit history using something like tags but I'm unsure I can use more than one tag by commit. Also, manging tags once created seems tiedous.